# style problem with jQueryUI Autocomplete widget (using remote datasource)

Tags: css, jquery-ui

`<input class="ui-autocomplete-input"/>` represents the text field to be autocompleted.

`<ul>...</ul>` contains the list of matching items from the text field input.  It is added to the document by remote call as you type.

`<ul>...</ul>` is added just inside the closing `</body>` tag.  I was expecting the `<ul>...</ul>` to be placed just after the `<input class="ui-autocomplete-input"/>`.  Because this does not happen, the `<ul>...</ul>` falls outside of the containing `div` and the resulting style is broken.

Suggestions?  Can I specify where the `<ul>...</ul>` gets placed in the document?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your source (so we can see exactly what we're working with here) but basically you need just need to find the parent and then appendTo

$("ul").appendTo($("input.ui-autocomplete-input").parent());

Comment: Indeed that's basically it:
`$("ul.ui-autocomplete").insertAfter($("input.ui-autocomplete"))`

The documentation implies that is what happens by default, but it turns out it is added after the body so it is always on top in IE (which doesn't do z-index).